Geometry Node: How would I convert a series of Curve Lines into a series of Planes

I am trying to procedurally make some pine trees from curves, and I want to make foliage cards.

I have a series of curves representing each branch (seen here as the "spines")
I have resampled it to N segments (in this case 8)
At each of the points I have created two instances of curve line whose angle is set by the user, and whose length is calculated from the factor parameter of the parent branch curve.

I wish to convert these V shapes of lines into planes one mesh per branch


I am not restricted to using these line curves, but the final result must have a controllable angle, taper, and segments, and be derived from the branch curve

Here is a simple example:

Instead of instantiating several lines at the individual points, I use a continuous line that is instantiated in the middle of the branches.
I simply divide it so that I can rotate its end point independently of the center point.
The advantage here is that I can then simply place individual grids (one grid per branch) whose points I can move to the positions of the previously created lines.
Since the points of the lines are numbered consecutively, this corresponds exactly to the indices of the created grids.

As you have unfortunately not shown your node tree and have not shared your blend file, I have kept this example generic.
However, it is relatively easy to modify and extend or customize according to your wishes.
(Blender 4.1.0+)

Thank you for your reply, I will try to figure out implementing this withing my setup. I hesitate to share my nodes only because the amount of previous steps that have lead to the point I'm at would be convoluted and detract from the more simple problem I am facing. If I can't find a solution from what you have provided I will make a stripped down Blend file and attach it to the original post. thank you again!

@quellenform I have an answer to how to “convert a series of Curves Lines into a series of Planes”, but first it’s not the best way to make low poly's trees as qellenform has shown previously, and secondly I made it but I can’t figure how it works!!! It’s not a joke, I just can’t… Do you think I should post there or ask to the community “how my blend works”? The blend: https://blend-exchange.com/b/1KbLxL6q/

after converting to @quellenform's system of making the curve I was able to get it working
